# Enabling Remote API in Docker on Mac OS X (boot2docker)

Tags: docker, boot2docker

I can't seem to figure out how to enable the remote API when using boot2docker. I am trying to use dockerode as follows:

```
Docker = require('dockerode')
docker = new Docker(socketPath: "/var/run/docker.sock")

container = docker.getContainer('<my_container_id>')

container.inspect (err, data) ->
  debug data
```

Data is null, despite there being a container with the id ''. I suspect this is because there is no /var/run/docker.sock on the OS X host, and that I would need to use something like:

```
var docker2 = new Docker({host: 'http://192.168.1.10', port: 3000});
```

... but can't figure out how to configure boot2docker or docker in the VirtualBox VM to enable access via http or tcp.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Docker, as configured by Boot2Docker, supports remote access on port 2375 *from the host OSX machine* by default; this is what is set up when it tells you to do `export DOCKER_HOST=tcp://192.168.59.103:2375`

If you want to access the port from another machine you need to configure VirtualBox networking to route traffic to that port.  This could be done by port forwarding with this command:

```
VBoxManage modifyvm "boot2docker-vm" --natpf1 "guestssh,tcp,,2375,,2375"
```

Then the address to use in your `new Docker` code is the IP address of your Mac.

You can also configure this in the VirtualBox GUI under boot2docker-vm/settings/network/advanced/port forwarding.

See [VirtualBox docs](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#networkingmodes).

Note, as described [here](http://docs.docker.com/articles/basics/#bind-docker-to-another-hostport-or-a-unix-socket) that this now allows anyone with IP access to your machine to control your Docker installation, which may be a security concern.

Comment: Thanks Bryan. Another thing that I'm struggling to figure out is how to use curl to talk to the docker API. Do you have some pointers?

Comment: best ask that as a separate question.

Answer (score 5):

For everybody that runs into that issue, most of the time you want to disable TLS when using something like boot2docker - which is build for dev and testing only (donno why boot2docker made the decision to enable TLS by default) 
It'll prevent you from accessing the remote API using basicly like every REST tool you can think about because none of them supports TLS based authentication without quite a lot of configuration.

So if you just want to develop within boot2docker, run this in your boot2docker console:

```
cp /etc/init.d/docker ~/docker.bak
sudo sed -i 's/DOCKER_TLS:=auto/DOCKER_TLS:=no/1' /etc/init.d/docker
sudo /etc/init.d/docker stop
sudo /etc/init.d/docker start
```

It will disable TLS and restart the docker deamon. Once done, you should be able to open `http://your-boot2docker-ip:2375/info` and get some output. Note that this is as of boot2docker 1.41. The name of the env variable repalced by the sed command above may change in future. Maybe they'll even disable TLS by default in future releases.

Comment: after two days I finally got api working thank to your post! big thanks from me!

Comment: is this mean that I have to access api from https for docker default setup?

Comment: Simply using https won't work since docker is not using basic auth but cert based client authentification.

Comment: You'd have to configure your https client - whatever it is - to use certificate based client authentication for the TLS handshake to happen. Usualy you got to point your https-client to the client certificate which you created in Docker. I guess most REST tools won't have support for such things. You may try fiddler or something similar - but I don't know for sure if they offer TLS client cert based auth.

Comment: Oh, details on client cert based TLS may be found here https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc783349(v=ws.10).aspx The Docker remote API guide shows you how to do it using cURL and wget. Funny: i just found this page why looking for compatible browsers: http://www.browserauth.net/tls-client-authentication

Comment: As of the latest release, you can now use server-side only auth and thus run the server in ssl mode without the need to authenticate your clients, see https://docs.docker.com/articles/https/ - Please note, this will encrypt your http connection using https (TLS) but it won't require authentication. So, everyone will be able to run docker commands. Docker currently only suppots authentication using client certificates - which makes it kinda hard to implement because it involves manual steps.

Answer (score 3):

In current version of boot2docker (1.3.1) you can do this by just mounting a volume to the container, eg:

```
$ docker run -it -v /var/run/docker.sock:/home/docker.sock myimage bash
[ root@51c0518f4d42:~ ]$ ls /home
docker.sock

Docker = require('dockerode')
docker = new Docker(socketPath: "/home/docker.sock")
// should work!
```

IMHO this is simpler and cleaner than messing around with VirtualBox port forwarding

This is actually that same as how most examples of using a Docker API client are set out, i.e. "just mount the docker socket into the container as a volume".

Perhaps like me you thought due to the way boot2docker works this wouldn't be possible.  After all, it appears that recent versions are set up to share volumes *from your OS X host* rather than the boot2docker vm, which is what you'd want most of the time.  But there is no `/var/run/docker.sock` path on your OS X host, so what is going on?

What actually happens is that the `/Users` dir is mounted from your host into the boot2docker vm. When you add a volume to a container under boot2docker it is still sharing whatever is at that path *in the vm*... it just happens that any paths under `/Users` in the vm are mounted from the host.  But any paths outside `/Users` will be from the boot2docker vm itself and not your host.

i.e.

```
$ boot2docker ssh
docker@boot2docker:~$ ls /var/run
acpid.pid        acpid.socket     docker.pid       docker.sock      sshd.pid         udhcpc.eth0.pid  udhcpc.eth1.pid  utmp
```

There is our docker socket file, and since it's outside the `/Users` directory we can link that path into our containers as a volume.

(For some reason this doesn't work:

```
$ docker run -it -v /var/run/docker.sock
```

...the socket file comes out as a `/var/run/docker.sock/` directory in our container - seems like a docker bug.)

We have to use the colon-separated form:

```
$ docker run -it -v /var/run/docker.sock:/home/docker.sock
```