# Docker remote API not accessible

Tags: docker, boot2docker

I installed boot2docker on my Windows 7 and initialized the VM.
Docker runs fine inside the VM, but I cannot access remote API on port 2375.
When connecting to port  2376 I get following reply:

```
docker@boot2docker:~$ curl http://localhost:2376/containers
§♥☺ ☻☻
```

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26828126/1515058) "Boot2Docker, supports remote access on port 2375 from the host".

I tried researching means to configure remote API, but the articles([1](http://www.virtuallyghetto.com/2014/07/quick-tip-how-to-enable-docker-remote-api.html),[2](http://blog.tmtk.net/2014/01/16/expose_docker_remote_api_on_centos.html),[3](http://blog.flux7.com/blogs/docker/docker-tutorial-series-part-8-docker-remote-api),[4](http://nofluffjuststuff.com/blog/tobias_gesellchen/2014/09/determine_whether_a_docker_container_is_running)) do not help me much. It would be handy to see where the remote access is configured.

Running following command I get:

```
docker@boot2docker:~$ ps -a -l | grep docker
 1117 root     /usr/local/bin/docker -d -D -g /var/lib/docker -H unix:// -H tcp://0.0.0.0:2376 --tlsverify --tlscacert=/
var/lib/boot2docker/tls/ca.pem --tlscert=/var/lib/boot2docker/tls/server.pem --tlskey=/var/lib/boot2docker/tls/serverkey
.pem
 1204 root     sshd: docker [priv]
 1206 docker   sshd: docker@pts/0
 1207 docker   -sh
 1364 docker   ps -a -l
 1365 docker   -sh
```

According to this [page](http://www.iana.org/assignments/service-names-port-numbers/service-names-port-numbers.xhtml?search=docker) ports are 2375 and 2376 for http and https respectively.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By default the Docker daemon on boot2docker only activates the TLS encrypted socket (port: 2376). To use boot2docker with an unencrypted Docker socket you have to disable TLS by adding `DOCKER_TLS=no` to your `/var/lib/boot2docker/profile` inside the boot2docker VM.

See the [boot2docker README file](https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker#tls-support) for more information.