# How to enable docker remote api in mac OS X?

Tags: docker, boot2docker

I'm new to docker, and I want to use java api to print my docker information. I read this [tutorial](http://docs.docker.com/reference/api/docker_remote_api/).I use boot2docker and print this command "boot2docker ip" to find my docker machine ip is

```
bash-3.2$ boot2docker ip
192.168.59.103
```

So,I use rest to connect docker.I input http://192.168.59.103:2376/info
and it can connect to it,but show nothing.So I guess it maybe I should make my docker enable rest. How should I do for it? I'm also new to mac OS X. please give more detail for me. Thanks

I use command:

```
curl -v http://192.168.59.103:2376/info
```

it show information :

```
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 192.168.59.103...
* Connected to 192.168.59.103 (192.168.59.103) port 2376 (#0)
> GET /info HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.37.1
> Host: 192.168.59.103:2376
> Accept: */*
> 

* Connection #0 to host 192.168.59.103 left intact
```

Comment: Use `curl` with the `-v` flag to get a better idea of what's happening: is there no server listening? Are you getting an error? Is the server giving an empty (but successful) response?

Comment: @NathanielWaisbrot Thanks for your hint. I have done and show the information in question. Then, What does it mean? How should I do?

Comment: As I mentioned below, boot2docker doesn't listen on 2376, especially in nont-TLS (http). only 2375. Did you start boot2docker (boot2docker up),

Comment: @VonC I'm sure I use the command "boot2docker up". And this command "docker -H tcp://192.168.59.103:2376 version" is ok. But, I'm new to docker, do it means boot2docker listen on 2376?

Comment: @v11 can you try the command-line setup (I have edited my answer below)

Comment: @VonC I have try what you edited below. Then how should I do? It still didn't work in rest remote api.

Comment: Does the `docker run hello-world` work?

Comment: @VonC It worked. I'm sure.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in "[Enabling Remote API in Docker on Mac OS X (boot2docker)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26828126/6309)", boot2docker supports [remote access on port 2375](https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker/blob/6b3e8b52589b4f45a38ce027acc370622a2c4be5/doc/FAQ.md#what-are-the-specs-of-the-vm) (non-TLS, instead of 2376 TLS), so try:

http://192.168.59.103:2375/info

More generally, follow [Boot2Docker on Mac](https://docs.docker.com/installation/mac/), for example "[from your command line](https://docs.docker.com/installation/mac/#from-your-command-line)"

```
boot2docker init
boot2docker start
boot2docker shellinit
eval "$(boot2docker shellinit)"
docker run hello-world
```

Comment: I try this ip : http://192.168.59.103:2375/info. and it show me can't connect to this. what is wrong with me? Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I can see the page about "Welcome to nginx!" via connect to "192.168,59,103". But I still can't connect to 192.168.59.103:2375/info. I think nginx just a web app.